# How to save documents like pdf,etc and images in sqlite

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize ORM with node/express.js and would like to save images or documents into sqlite database

Comment: Another approach might be to store the blobs in a blob storage service such as Azure blob storage or Amazon S3 and store only the URI  to the blob in the DB.

Comment: Can you please show us, what you've tried so far?

Comment: @SelloMkantjwa Thank you i'll take that into consideration

Comment: @MichaelHirschler Thank you i've just made the basic template for nodemailer currently and implemented with mailtrap ,but what i wanted to know was if i can send images,documents etc with nodemailer and rather can save images and documents in sqlite (not native but using sequelize). so that if its not compatible with sqlite , i can switch to diff rbdms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked out `BLOB` column [datatype](http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/2.0/api/datatypes/) ? It allows you to save binary data.This way, you could have files of any type stored as blobs in the db.

By default you could store ~1 GB max. size image/document in a SQLite BLOB field. However, it can be increased by setting [SQLITE_MAX_LENGTH](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)

Comment: ah thank you sir but the documention doesnt realy explain much about BLOB so i had to take reference from somewhere else about saving images,etc .